# Vercel: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, symlink

Tags: reactjs, typescript, build, nestjs, vercel

This is my repository https://github.com/Shrinivassab/Portfolio
I am trying to create a portfolio website. When I try to run `vercel build`
I am getting the below error

```
Traced Next.js server files in: 1.490s
Created all serverless functions in: 788.915ms
Collected static files (public/, static/, .next/static): 4.085ms
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, symlink 'getExperience.func' -> 'D:\Coding Examples\portfolio\.vercel\output\functions\api\getPageInfo.func'
```

Do any suggestions please? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 13):

Running VS Code as admin on windows solved this issue for me.

Comment: Didn't know that this was available - but it sorted out the symlink permissions issue for me too. Right click on the vscode icon and select "Run as administrator."

Comment: Solved the same problem for a Sveltekit Build with "adapter-vercel"

Answer (score 0):

Run `yarn dev`(or `npm run dev`) in your project file

Then run the `terminal` as administrator and cd your project folder then run `vercel` build command

After then, delete the folder inside `.vercel\output\functions\_next\data`
and deploy `vercel deploy --prebuilt`

I could get help from some youtube comments. and it works for me